# How can I keep Microsoft Word's PrintDate field code from becoming plain text when converting my document to a pdf?

Tags: pdf, ms-word

In my Microsoft Word document, I have a field code to print the date the document was last printed ("PrintDate").  When I print my Word version of the document, every paper copy shows the date that copy came off the printer.  However, when I convert my Word document to a pdf, the field code becomes static text with the date that I converted the document to a pdf.  Any subsequent printing of the pdf copy will always just show the date the pdf version of the document was created, instead of the date the copy came off the printer.

I know I can create the pdf document without the PrintDate field code, insert a text field, and then use "JavaScript | Set Document Actions | Document Will Print" to make that text field operate like Word's PrintDate field code, but I'm using the Word document as a blank template for others to fill out and then they create pdf documents from it.  It would be simpler to not have to leave instructions for everyone on how to insert the javascript and, instead, have it part of the blank Word template.  I honestly don't understand why Adobe doesn't just convert the field code to javascript automatically, which brings me to my question...

**Is there a way to convert the Word document to a pdf, but retain dynamic field codes, such as PrintDate and SaveDate?**

Comment: This is an end-user, not a programming question and therefore off-topic on Stack Overflow. It should be asked in a venue such as Super User. But no, that's not supported in current versions of Word.

Answer (score 0):

You can't prevent field codes in Word being converted to their results in a PDF.